# Pasting multiple nodes in jsTree

Tags: nodes, jstree, paste

The documentation for the CRRM plugin for jsTree states that the copy() method "*Copies a node (prepares it for pasting)*" and takes a parameter that "*can be a DOM node, jQuery node or selector pointing to an element within the tree*".
All of this is **singular**.

For paste() it says "*Pastes copied or cut nodes inside a node*". Implying that it supports the pasting of **multiple** nodes.

I have been unable to figure out, however, how to copy multiple nodes. Is it possible? If so, what do I need to pass to the copy() method?

I should mention that I am using the checkboxes plugin, and node selection for copy is done using them. Currently I call the get_checked() method to get the checked nodes. 
It does not work to pass the result of this call to copy(). What I end up doing is looping the result of get_checked(), get the id of each node, and then call copy() and paste() for each one.

The trouble is, my handler for the "move.jstree" event (fired when pasting) does an ajax call to do the serverside update. If I am pasting 10 nodes then I get 10 ajax calls which is silly. I want to do one ajax call that handles the pasting of multiple nodes. It must be possible, right?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question.

All I needed to do was concatenate the node id's into a selector string and call...

```
$('jstreediv').jstree('copy', '#node1, #node2, #mode3');
```

...to copy multiple nodes, and then simply call paste to paste them all...

```
$('jstreediv').jstree('paste', '#id-of-target-folder');
```

So it was really just a documentation issue.

Comment: Where are you concatenating the node IDs? In my copy function   `.on('copy_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
   data.node.data = $.extend(true, {}, data.original.data);
   console.log(data);
  })` I only see one of my copied nodes.